# Python: String generator program about recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I want to write a string generator program, when doing the recursive part something goes wrong. I really want to know what's wrong with that. If you can give me some advice on how to analyze the recursive problems I will appreciate a lot.

The code may be a little long, some patience may be needed here. A lot thanks again

```
def lit(s): return lambda Ns: set([s]) if len(s) in Ns else null
def alt(x,y): return lambda Ns: x(Ns) | y(Ns)
def opt(x,y): return alt(epsilon, x)
def seq(x,y): return lambda Ns: genseq(x, y, Ns)
def plus(x): return lambda Ns: genseq(x, star(x), Ns, startx=1)
def star(x): return lambda Ns: opt(plus(x))(Ns)

epsilon = lit('')
null = frozenset()

def ns(): return lambda n : set(range(n+1))
```

The code above is the basic function in the generator, i will put some example here to help understand what they can do.

```
>>> a = opt(lit('a'))
>>> b = lit('b')
>>> n = ns()

>>> print b(n(3))
set(['b'])

>>> print a(n(3))
set(['', 'a'])

>>> print seq(a,b)(n(3))
set(['b', 'ab'])

>>> print plus(b)(n(3))
set(['b', 'bb', 'bbb'])

>>> print star(b)(n(3))
set(['', 'b', 'bb', 'bbb'])
```

Code about the function genseq() below is the main part and I have two version here.

Version 1(This is the correct version):

```
def genseq(x, y, Ns, startx=0):
    "startx here is to avoid x keep returning '' " 
    if not Ns:
        return null
    xmatches = x(set(range(startx, max(Ns)+1)))
    Ns_x = set(len(m) for m in xmatches)
    Ns_y = set(n-m for n in Ns for m in Ns_x if n-m>=0)
    ymatches = y(Ns_y)
    return set(m1 + m2
               for m1 in xmatches for m2 in ymatches
               if len(m1+m2) in Ns)
```

Version 2(This is the version I write):

```
def genseq(x, y, Ns, startx=0):
    if not Ns:
        return null
    Nsy = set(range(max(Ns)+1))
    Nsx = set(range(startx, max(Ns)+1))
    return set(m1 + m2
               for m1 in x(Nsx) for m2 in y(Nsy)
               if len(m1 + m2) in Ns)
```

when using my version, errors will occur saying that:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

I really want to figure out what's wrong in my code. How the infinite recursion happens?

Comment: how did you call the function? also, what is `genseq2`?

Comment: What are `Nssx` and `Nss`? And why does `a = opt(lit('a'))` not throw an error when `opt` requires 2 parameters?

Comment: I'm sorry about the mistakes."genseq2", "Nssx" and "Nss"are modified。 
As for a=opt(lit('a')), that is correct because a is a lambda-function-object here, that is legal in Python.